# How to set wifi configuration priority?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to programmatically register wifi configurations along with priorities (i.e if multiple registered wifi networks are available the system should connect to the one with the highest priority).

The documentation says that [WifiConfiguration.priority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration#priority) has been removed in API level 26 but doesn't provide any alternative.

In API level 29 there is a new network API with a [WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder.setPriority](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder#setPriority(int)) method, but it's only available for devices with Android >= 10.

Is it somehow possible to set priorities for wifi configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration

> This class was deprecated in API level 29. Use
> WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder to create NetworkSpecifier and
> WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder to create WifiNetworkSuggestion. This
> will become a system use only object in the future.

WifiNetworkSuggestion's require the user to approve the connection. Only once the connection is approved will the platform consider a network for auto-connection in future.

For setting the priority, use:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder#setPriority(int)

Edit:

See:

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

> Both new apps and app updates must target at least Android 9 (API
> level 28).

Soon this will change to requiring updates to target Android 10 / Api Level 29.

Comment: Unfortunately this API is not available before Android 10 and I definitely need a working solution for Android 7/8/9